# ReactJS highlight blog post that comes from the server

Tags: reactjs, highlightjs

I've been trying to use highlight.js with my react project , but it never worked.
I have a blog, and for each post I fetch the post data from the server.
Unfortunately - highlight.js does not work properly when it comes to dynamic data and async proccess.
Lets say we have this code that i fetch:

```
bla blba blahbla blba blahbla blba blahbla blba blah...
<code><div class="test"></div></code>
bbla blba blah....
```

So , I did try to import highlight.js with the css theme, and used hljs.highlightAll() , but it didn't work properly.
Maybe there is some other solution \ library where I can highlight the code?
What's the alternative?
thank you.

```
import { React, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import hljs from "../../node_modules/highlight.js/lib/core";
import "../../node_modules/highlight.js/styles/arta.css";
import "./BlogPost.css";

function BlogPost(props) {
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

  const updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll("code").forEach((block) => {
      hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getPostData();
    updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting();
  }, []);

  // GetPostDataById(id);
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: postData }}></div>;
}

export default BlogPost;
```

result:
[image]

as you can see - the background gets darker , but not really highlighted text.

Comment: Did you try using `react-syntax-highlighter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not importing the entire `highlight.js` library so you can just do `import hljs from 'highlight.js'` instead of going into the node modules folder to get it. Also you are not specifying the language you want to highlight in with the class of the code block. In the example I am just going to hard code the `postData` with `class='language-javascript'` for the `<code>` block to get the correct syntax highlighting. So here is a working example:

[Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/highlight-js-react-bw4qpw)

```
import { React, useEffect } from 'react'
import hljs from 'highlight.js'
import '../../node_modules/highlight.js/styles/arta.css'

const postData = `<pre><code class="language-javascript">console.log('hello');</code></pre>`

function BlogPost(props) {
  const updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('code').forEach((block) => {
      hljs.highlightElement(block)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    updateCodeSyntaxHighlighting()
  }, [])

  // GetPostDataById(id);
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: postData }}></div>
}
```

Comment: I find a example https://codesandbox.io/s/react-marked-highlight-js-forked-x6zrfl?file=/src/index.js. But I use the same code and the same version in my local it doesn't work. The style seems is null. Could you known what is the problem of mime?

Comment: In my project, I use css modules. Does it has a enfluence?

Comment: @Ha0ran it's hard telling what is going on in your local project without seeing it. Unless you are overriding the css stated by highlightjs then your css modules shouldn't matter. When you right click and inspect the `<code></code>` does it have the correct classes applied to it? If you inspect the code block in the codesandbox example you can see the classes `hljs language-javascript` applied. Also are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: I finally solved it by change webpack config. When match /\.css$/, I set modules: { mode: 'icss' }. When match /\module\.css$/, I set modules: { mode: 'local' }